# Rudin's RCA $2.20$ theorem $(c)$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

There are the definitions which we need for the theorem:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

There are the theorem $2.20$ and proof of its part $(a)$ and $(b)$:
[image]

[image]

There are the proofs of part $(c)$, $(d)$ and $(e)$:

The proofs of $(c)$, $(d)$, and $(e)$ will use the following observation: If $\lambda$ is a positive Borel measure on $R^k$ and $\lambda(E)$ $=$ $m(E)$ for all boxes $E$, then the same equality holds for all open sets $E$, by property $2.19(d)$, and therefore for all Borel sets $E$, since $\lambda$ and $m$ are regular (Theorem $2.18$).

To prove $(c)$, fix $x$ $\in$ $R^k$ and define $\lambda(E)$ $=$ $m(E+x)$.

It is clear that $\lambda$ is then a measure; by $(a)$, $\lambda(E)$ $=$ $m(E)$ for all boxes, hence $m(E+x)$ $=$ $m(E)$ for all Borel sets $E$.

The same equality holds for every $E$ $\in$ $\mathfrak M$, because of $(b)$.

I don't understand why is it clear in $(c)$ that $\lambda$ is a measure.
I also don't understand how does $(a)$ imply, that $\lambda(E)$ $=$ $m(E)$ for all boxes?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This might get closed as the other one did. There are too many pictures and it's quite hard to follow. I recommend making the question more focused, and if you have to, feel free to leave out further details such as other lemmas and prerequisite theorems as it's likely that many readers know them.

Answer (score 1):

We can demonstrate this using the second part of (e), that is, when $T$ is invertible, $\Delta(T) = |\det T|$ (this is not obvious, but it can be proven by proving it for $T$ that generate $GL(n, \mathbb{R})$, e.g. $T$ being each of the three elementary row operations).

Suppose $Y \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a linear subspace of dimension $k < n$. By basic linear algebra, there is an orthogonal matrix $A$ such that $A(Y) = \mathbb{R}^{k} \times \{0\}^{n - k}$. In particular, $A : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is an isometric isomorphism, so $A$ and $A^{-1}$ are both continuous, hence measurable. Thus $Y = A^{-1}AY = A^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^{k} \times \{0\}^{n - k})$ is Borel measurable. Since $\det A = \pm 1$, we get
$$m(Y) = m(A(Y)) = m(\mathbb{R}^{k} \times \{0\}^{n - k}) = m(\mathbb{R}^k) \cdot m(\{0\}^{n - k}) = \infty \cdot 
0 = 0.$$

Comment: @Obito Why is $\Delta(T)$ equal of $|detT|$ when T is invertible? I also don't understand how does the fact that det $A$ $=$ $1$, or $-1$ guarantees that $Y$ is Borel-measurable?

Comment: @JohnNash I've fixed my answer to elaborate those points.

Comment: Great job on gaining your first bounty!